# I want to vertical-align text in select box

Tags: css, gwt, select, vertical-alignment

I want to vertically align the text in select box. I tried using

```
select{
   verticle-align:middle;
}
```

however it does not work in any browsers. Chrome seems to align the text in select box to the center as a default. FF aligns it to the top and IE aligns it to the bottom. Is there any way to achieve this? I am using GWT's Select widget in UIBinder.

This is currently what I have:

```
select{
    height: 28px !important;
    border: 1px solid #ABADB3;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: is `font-size:22px;` an option?

Comment: I already have font-size set to 14px. I don't think this will work throughout browsers...

Comment: Your first example shows "verticle-align" rather than "vertical-align" - these sorts of typos will definitely cause you problems.

Comment: Still an issue in 2016!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Your best option will probably be to adjust the top padding & compare across browsers. It's not perfect, but I think it's as close as you can get.

```
padding-top:4px;
```

The amount of padding you need will depend on the font size.

Tip: If your font is set in `px`, set padding in `px` as well. If your font is set in `em`, set the padding in `em` too.

**EDIT**

These are the options I think you have, since vertical-align isn't consistant across the browsers.

A. Remove height attribute and let the browser handle it. This usually works the best for me.

```
 <style>
    select{
        border: 1px solid #ABADB3;
        margin: 0;
        padding: auto 0;
        font-size:14px;
    }
    </style>
    <select>
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option>number 2</option>
    </select>
```

---

B. Add top-padding to push down the text. (Pushed down the arrow in some browsers)

```
<style>
select{
    height: 28px !important;
    border: 1px solid #ABADB3;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 0 0 0;
    font-size:14px;
}
</style>
<select>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>number 2</option>
</select>
```

---

C. You can make the font larger to try and match the select height a little nicer.

```
<style>
select{
    height: 28px !important;
    border: 1px solid #ABADB3;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    font-size:17px;
}
</style>
<select>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>number 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear example. I tried option 2 and it added padding to the textbox part of the select, so the arrow button that is used to enlarge the list stayed the same... Increasing the font size is not an option so I need to find other solution.. Thanks.

Comment: In my experience that doesn't work, as any padding you to the top not only lowers the text, it also lowers the button with the arrow that opens the list of options.

Comment: if your select box is bigger, what worked for me is setting padding= box height/5, só my select box has a heigh of 35 and i set padding of 7px, that seemed to fix it

Comment: AS J.Pablo Fernández stated, padding pushes the arrow down, which isn't an acceptable option for some people, especially aesthetically-focused clients.

Comment: what is `padding: auto`?

Answer (score 22):

I stumbled across this set of css properties which seem to vertically align the text in sized select elements in Firefox:

```
select
{
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
}
```

If anything, though, it pushes the text down even farther in IE8.  If I set the box-sizing property back to border-box, it at least doesn't make IE8 any worse (and FF still applies the -moz-box-sizing property).  It would be nice to find a solution for IE, but I'm not holding my breath.

**Edit:**  Nix this.  It doesn't work after testing.  For anyone interested, though, the problem seems to stem from built-in styles in FF's forms.css file affecting input and select elements.  The property in question is **line-height:normal !important**.  It cannot be overridden.  I've tried.  I discovered that if I delete the built-in property in Firebug I get a select element with reasonably vertically-centered text.

Answer (score 10):

My solution is to add padding-top for select targeted to firefox only like this

```
// firefox vertical aligment of text
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    select {
        padding-top: 13px;
   }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution the best! This way the padding does not mess up webkit browsers. (I haven't tested on IE yet though)

Answer (score 4):

So far this is working fine for me:

```
line-height: 100%;
```

Comment: Easiest solution and working!

Answer (score 4):

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that simply setting the line-height and height to the same pixel quantity produced the most consistent result.  By "most consistent" I mean optimally consistent but of course it is not 100% "pixel-perfect" across browsers.  Additionally I found that Firefox (v. 17.x) tends to crowd the option text to the right against the drop-down arrow; I alleviated this with a small amount of padding-right set on the OPTION element only.  This setting does not affect appearance in IE 7-9.

My result:

```
select, option {
    font-size:10px;
    height:19px;
    line-height: 19px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

option {
    padding-right:6px; /* Firefox */
}
```

NOTE -- my SELECT element uses a smaller font, 10px.  Obviously you will need to adjust proportions accordingly for your specific UI context.

Answer (score 2):

just had this problem, but for mobile devices, mainly **mobile firefox**. The trick for me was to define a **height**, **padding**, **line height**, and finally **box sizing**, all on the select element. Not using your example numbers here, but for the sake of an example:

```
padding: 20px;
height: 60px;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-box-sizing: padding-box;
-moz-box-sizing: padding-box;
box-sizing: padding-box;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried as following and it worked for me:

```css
select {
     line-height:normal;
     padding:3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can give :

```
select{
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

and to parent you have to give position:relative.
it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the "line-height" attribute

Like this:

```
select{
    height: 28px !important;
    line-height: 28px;
}
```

Here you are some documentation about this attribute:

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/line-height

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Comment: Line-height doesn't work on the select elements and setting the height doesn't vertically center the text on ie8.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use `height` and `line-height` with the same values, but the proved to be inconsistent across the interwebs. My current approach is to mix that with padding like so.

```
select {
  font-size:14px;
  height:18px;
  line-height:18px;
  padding:5px 0;
  width:200px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

You could also use `padding` for the horizontal value instead of the `width` + `text-align`

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and been working on it for hours. I've finally come up something that works.

Basically nothing I tried worked in every situation until I positioned a div to replicate the text of the first option over the select box and left the actual first option blank. I used {pointer-events:none;} to let users click through the div.

HTML

```
    <div class='custom-select-container'>
      <select>
        <option></option>
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
      </select>
      <div class='custom-select'>
        Select an option
      </div>
    <div>
```

CSS

```
.custom-select{position:absolute; left:28px; top:10px; z-index:1; display:block; pointer-events:none;}
```

Comment: Pointer events is unsupported by Internet Explorer (all versions), so I advise to not use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found that only adding `padding-top` pushed down the grey dropdown arrow box on the right, which was undesirable.

The method that worked for me was to go into the inspector and incrementally add `padding` until the text was centered. This will also reduce the size of the dropdown icon, but it will be centered as well so it isn't as visually disturbing.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been fixed in Firefox Nightly and will be in the next firefox build.

Please see this bug for more information https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=610733

Answer (score 0):

You can also try margin:

```
.select{
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The nearest general solution i know uses box-align property, as described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-align.asp).
Working example is [here](http://jsbin.com/oxafev/3) (i can test it only on Chrome, believe that has equivalent for other browsers too).

CSS:

```
select{
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-moz-box;
  display:box;
  height: 30px;;
}
select:nth-child(1){
  -webkit-box-align:start;
  -moz-box-align:start;
  box-align:start;
}
select:nth-child(2){
  -webkit-box-align:center;
  -moz-box-align:center;
  box-align:center;
}
select:nth-child(3){
  -webkit-box-align:end;
  -moz-box-align:end;
  box-align:end;
}
```