# firefox not vertically centering select input content with height specified

Tags: css, select, height, vertical-alignment

here's an image of whats going on:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/217/ffbug.png/

here's my code:

```
select {
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

in chrome and firefox, it vertically-aligns the select values perfectly. in firefox, the values are stuck to the top of the select.

i've tried adding `vertical-align: middle` and `line-height: 40px`, both of which changed nothing.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439782/i-want-to-vertical-align-text-in-select-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i decided to put it in a div with this code:

```
.search li select {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.search li div {
    height: 32px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

the div background is same as the select background.

its pretty well centered in FF IE and chrome, only thing is the arrow is inside the padding as well...oh well...sometimes you can't win i guess.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;` on that element. Your text will be automatically centerd.

Comment: That will 'work', but it will also change the button within the `<select>` which is .. pretty ugly lookin. http://i.imgur.com/V64sW.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS code:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  select {
    padding-top: 13px;
  }
}
```

This should work, when you want multiple browser support.