# IE8 - Vertical alignment of a <select> element with a custom height

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

When applying a custom height on a `select` element, the text in IE8 is being vertically aligned to the bottom:
http://jsfiddle.net/4DYPf/8/

```
<select>
    <option value="1">123</option>
    <option value="1">456</option>
</select>

select
{
   border: 2px solid #CDCDCD;
   height: 50px;   
}
```

Is there a way to align in to the middle?

Comment: What are you trying to align to the middle?  the option element?   or the select element to the middle of its parent?

Comment: The option element (which is the behavior in IE9, FF and Chrome).

Comment: Have you tried searching stackoverflow first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439782/i-want-to-vertical-align-text-in-select-box, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911111/how-to-make-sure-select-option-text-align-in-the-center-in-ie,

Comment: Yeah, I found these questions. The answers in the first one didn't really work out, and the second one is regarding horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no a css answer, but if you really need to center the text and you use jQuery, this is a way to fake that alignment:
http://jsfiddle.net/cadence96/7MZHv/1/

It consists of placing an absoluted span over the white space of the select tag, then the current text of the selected option will be inserted within this span. That way you can style its text the way you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I was really hoping for a css only solution (although apparently it may not exists). In addition, I'm handling an application where there are already dozens of DropDownLists with a height, so having to add a `span` is also something I would prefer to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

If you add `padding:1em 0px;` to your `select` style it vertically aligns your text to the middle but also squashes the drop down arrow.

See example:http://jsfiddle.net/TfwsE/1/

Comment: I tried adding a `padding` style (that's how I handled a similar issue with textboxes in IE8, btw), but that look of the arrow doesn't really pass for what I need...

Comment: Have you considered the jQueryUI autocomplete combobox. It is highly customizable http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox I believe you can just remove the autocomplete functionality.

Comment: Also, if you set the borders on your SELECT to 0 it won't look so odd if that's a possible option.