# IE7 issue with Select height

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

```
height: 22px;
```

In all browsers the text is vertically aligned middle except IE7.

I tried these CSS rules but no luck:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 12px;
padding:0 0 3px 0;
```

in IE7 the text sticks to the bottom.

[image]

I wouldn't consider the meta tag set for IE7 standard.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

for MSIE browsers you need to pre-set the font rules for input and select elements...

```
input, select {font-family:'Times New Roman';font-size:100%; line-height:1.5em}
```

Usually this is done in a `reset.css` file. You can test this requirement by using the `View>Text Size` menu in IE...without the rule the text in select and input elements does not change size... with the rule it does... matching other browsers.

MSIE browsers have a setting "Enable visual styles on buttons and controls in web pages" which affects the rendering of select and other form elements.

to align the label element with a control I like this design pattern:

```
[label]Select:[select][option]this option[/option][/select][/label]
```

for Apple and Mobile type layouts

```
[label]Select:[br/][select][option]this option[/option][/select][/label]
```

again... you need to change the default style rules for label elements to make them consistent with the input and select elements.

```
label{font-size:100%; font-weight:bold}
```

Comment: By using height for select elements any font settings won't affect IE7 to vertically align the height. I already tried your lines.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is also present with IE8. I tried your example using IE8 & IE7 (Developer tools) and it behaved the same. take a look at this post:

[IE8 - Vertical alignment of a <select> element with a custom height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200618/ie8-vertical-alignment-of-a-select-element-with-a-custom-height)

This one also states, that there is no possibility to even center a select element in IE:

[how to make sure select option text align in the center in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911111/how-to-make-sure-select-option-text-align-in-the-center-in-ie)

Answer (score -2):

@Nima

You can also do that giving **line-height** to **select** in an **IE-Only** Stylesheet. In one of my assignment, I also had the same problem in IE. So, what I did is, I made an **IE only** style sheet for targeting IE andget required results. For making an **IE-Only** style sheet, you can refer [this](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) or [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/how-to-create-ie-specific-css-stylesheet/).

Comment: Except line-height doesn't actually affect a select in IE7. Which is what the question was about.