# Cannot nullify the padding on a <select> in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, html-select

I've got a problem with IE8.

I've got a select box to choose capacitance units pF, nF and mF.

Now, the text is a little bit down, even though I set `padding:0`, and it cuts the text.

And so the 'pF' option actually looks like 'nF' which is unacceptable.

[image]

I wonder if there is any fix at all. I can't think of nothing other than setting padding to 0 which doesn't work once again. Setting small `line-height` also doesn't do anything either.

CSS:

```
select {
    width: 40px;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 0px;
    font: 8pt Helvetica;
}
```

Any ideas?

Edit: There you go for **JSFIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/zuYsF/

See that 'pF' is selected by default, and it actually looks like 'nF'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is padding causing a problem, this might have more to do with line-height

So try setting the line height to the height of the box minus the border top and border bottom (which seems to be 4px in total judging by that image from looks...) that height is probably about 12px...

```
line-height: 12px;
```

If this doesn't fix it you will have to reproduce it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can tinker with the code to give an actual working example back to you.

Please note that form elements are notoriously unreliable styling wise, and you can't get away with everything. `display: block` can do wonders, but wouldn't help in this case.

This seems to be cheer limitation of the `<select>` tag styling... In all browsers really.

You might want to check this question, which doesn't seem totally unrelated.

[I want to vertical-align text in select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439782/i-want-to-vertical-align-text-in-select-box)

Comment: It's also what I thought for, but it doesn't work for some reason, even I make it like this: line-height: 14px !important;

Comment: also, it google chrome it shows the line-height property as 'normal', even though it does see the custom line-height declared.

Comment: Please note this in your question more clearly. Make a jsfiddle, reproducing the problem.

Comment: Is it possible maybe to select the inner part of select with css pseudo selector?

Comment: That would make sense, but I'm afraid that is not going to work. Form elements pre-date current day standards, their behavior is quirky at best... I think your best bet for a quick fix here is to make sure the height of the box always accomedates at least the height of the text you want to have.

Comment: Yes, but apparently there is no answer to that, I'll have to admit it's impossible and probably go for another font, like serif, to set on the older browsers, unless someone else provides an answer to that.