# Select box text stuck to top of box in FF

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-select

I have a select field and no matter what I do I can't get the text to stop sticking to the top of the box.

Here is an example of how it looks:

[image]

If I use `padding-top` then it pushes down the arrow button as well, which I don't want. I have also tried `line-height` with no effect.

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
#header .nav .misc .search .search_holder .cats select {
    width: 111px;
    height: 29px;
    border-top: 1px solid #97ad00;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #97ad00;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    padding-left: 8px;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: url('../images/search-cats-bg.png') 0 0 repeat-x;
    color: #b2b2b2;
}

#header .nav .misc .search .search_holder .cats select option {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

#header .nav .misc .search .search_holder .cats select option.last {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

**Edit:** Added HTML.

HTML:

```
<div class="cats">
    <select id="search_cats" class="search_cats" name="cat">
        <option value="all">All Categories</option>
        <option value="sports">Sports Cards</option>
        <option value="gaming">Gaming Cards</option>
        <option value="non-sport">Non-Sport Cards</option>
        <option value="supplies" class="last">Supplies & Storage</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

**Edit:** Seems it can't really be fixed, found this question:

[I want to vertical-align text in select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439782/i-want-to-vertical-align-text-in-select-box)

If you look at the answer from "Shelly Skeens" then you will find that FF decided to set the built-in `line-height` to `normal !important` and hence it can't be overridden.

Comment: can you post your code, or post it to jsfiddle?

Comment: try `vertical-align: baseline;`

Comment: Sorry all, just posted the CSS.

Comment: remove the padding off the options and apply it to the select instead

Comment: insted of padding, try adding a line-height

Comment: Your css works fine can You post html code too?

Comment: What browser is this in?  I just cheked inb IE9 (http://jsfiddle.net/uBdsE/) and it's vertically aligned in the middle.

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/b2Vq6/2/ your code works fine if there is problem is relevant to #header or .nav ,.misc .search .search_holder

Comment: @alan Ok, this is weird. FF it sticks to the top, Chrome is vertically centered, IE8 is stuck to the bottom and IE7 there is no padding at all. That's from the example link you gave.

Comment: @afshin Nope, as I just explained to alan, that sticks to the top as well in FF.

Comment: Please clean up your css, you have 7/8 selectors per declaration. You should have somewhere between 1-3, 3 being too many.
.cats select would be enough in this case.

Comment: @pablo There is nothing wrong with the way it's done, if you prefer to do it another way then that is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

try add that

```
.cats * { line-height: 16px; }
```

Comment: Add it where? As I stated I have already tried using line-height and it didn't work. :(

Comment: i tested your code works fine, maybe something else, could you please post everything? header and the nav too

Answer (score 0):

works fine on google chrome ,and google developer tools [image: answer to select box qestion]

Comment: Yes, the main issue really appears to be in FF. Chrome is fine.