# css inconsistency with firefox - select form fields

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a form with `input` and `select` fields all at `height:32px`.
Firefox aligns the text to the top while all the other browsers align center. 
I would like to align the text to center, but seem to be having problems.
Any suggestions please? [HERES MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/ULQNQ/1/)

[image]

```
<select id="month" class="" name="month">
    <option value="1">February</option>
    <option value="2">March</option>
    <option value="3">April</option>
    <option value="4">May</option>
    <option value="5">June</option>
    <option value="6">July</option>
    <option value="7">August</option>
    <option value="8">September</option>
    <option selected="" value="9">October</option>
    <option value="10">November</option>
    <option value="11">December</option>
    <option value="12">undefined</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value='some text' />
```

**update**: `line-height` didnt seem to do anything

```
#month, input {height:32px; line-height:32px; vertical-align:middle;}
#month select{line-height:32px;}
```

Comment: Have u tried the line-height property of select? Make it same as height

Comment: @xfx http://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/ULQNQ/2/ didnt do anything

Comment: my solution is use padding, and some css hack

Comment: #month{padding: 6px 0;}, I tried it in jsfiddle, it works

Comment: @xfx thank you! can you put that as an answer and i will use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution is use padding, and some css hack

```
#month{padding: 6px 0;}
```

I tried it in jsfiddle, it works

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you give height for select box and observe the text align in various browsers is is different implementation
firfox -- text align from top left
IE- text align in the bottom
chrome -align in the center

One solution is to give the padding to the select box it also a minimal solution, because if you top padding to fix for the firfox then in IE the padding adds to the top and the text align to further bottom. Another problem is as much the padding you give that padding will applicable to the select dropdown button also.
best solution is please avoid the height for select box and keep the default height for the box.
For further reference please visit the link. this may clarify 
[I want to vertical-align text in select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439782/i-want-to-vertical-align-text-in-select-box)