# Why I can't align on the middle the text of a drop down list in Firefox?

Tags: html, css

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/8UA3J/1/) :

```
<select class="dropdown">
    <option value="1">Select</option>
    <option value="2">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>    
</select>

.dropdown
{
    padding:0 8px 0 8px;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height:26px;
    line-height:26px;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#000000;
    width:425px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

on Firefox the text is not aligned in the middle. Why? How can I fix it? (Firefox 16.0.2)

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to vertical-align text in select box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439782/i-want-to-vertical-align-text-in-select-box)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 .dropdown{ background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px solid #000000; color: #000000; font-size: 13px; margin: 0; padding: 8px; vertical-align: middle; width: 425px; }
```

---