# Items inside select box looks weird in ie8

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a select box I made,that looks OK on every browsers except IE8 ,in IE8 the items are near the bottom and not in the middle.

link:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/107452929/select/index.html

Comment: possible duplicate: [I want to vertical-align text in select box](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5439782/944681)

Answer (score 3):

Use `padding` instead of the `height` property to style the `select` list ...

```
select { padding:4px 0; }
```

Comment: ok,but if I do that the narrow in the right side is not longer in the right height....