# Why is the text in this drop down not vertically centered in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want to vertical-align text in select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439782/i-want-to-vertical-align-text-in-select-box)

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pollo/pYrBs/) the text in the drop down list is vertically centered in IE and Chrome...but not in Firefox where it is vertically top aligned. How do I center it in Firefox without disrupting the other browsers?

### HTML

```
<select>
    <option value="One" selected="selected">Test text one</option>
    <option value="Two">Test text two</option>
    <option value="Three">Test text three</option>
    <option value="Four">Test text four</option>
</select>
```

### CSS

```
select {
    height: 30px;
    width: 260px;
    border: 1px solid #A9A3A3;
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    }
```

Comment: misread at first. (horizontal vs vertical...) Updated my answer to include vertical alignment.

Comment: Check out this post. That may answer your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css

Comment: The actual reason for this is because Firefox specifies "line-height:normal !important" for select elements in its forms.css, which cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is not to assign a height to the select but to add padding to match the height of the other elements.

Comment: No, that pushes down the arrow in the drop down list as well.

Comment: Works great if you're overflowing the arrow anyways...

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies with fiddle. Their iframe will only have the minimal necessary size (in firefox at least). Try something like

```
div {
    height: 10em;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and place a `<div>` around your `<select>`. In a real scenario you might want to use `height: 100%`, absolute positioning or just modify the attributes of whatever tag contains your select.

---

---

misread your question at first, here the answer for *horizontal* alignment

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
```

(or whatever tag is above the `<select>`)

---

alternatively add the following

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

but in general it is a good idea to set some values for the `body` to avoid cross-browser differences (e.g. padding, margin and text-align).

Comment: hmm ok might not be fiddles fault but in fact different behaviours of the `iframe` tag in the different browsers. still: in any real scenario my solution should work.

Comment: the problem is with the actual text in firefox. Adding margin-left and right to auto will not fix the problem. Try to create a simple `<select>` and open the HTML in firefox. You will see that it is not centred vertically. However, it is centred vertically in IE, Edge and Chrome.